# Why is this code executed but ignored?

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint-2010, form-submit, pageload

In my Sharepoint page, on form submission, the elements revert to their original state (if a checkbox was unchecked to begin, was checked by a user, it reverts back to unchecked, etc.).

Fair enough.

But I want to "save state" and return those sorts of things back to the way they were. One thing in particular is the visibility of a Dropdownlist. If it was visible when the "Save" button was selected, it should return to being visible after the form is submitted; the two DropDownLists, of which at most one are visible at any given time, start off invisible or, more specifically, "slid up" like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').hide();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').hide();
});
```

In trying to save the visible state of the DropDownLists, I've added bools:

```
bool paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen = false;
bool paymentToAVendorDropDownChosen = false;
```

...and then assign them when the Save button is selected:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Note current state of elements, so can be restored after saving/submitting
        paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen = rbPaymentToIndividual.Checked;
        paymentToAVendorDropDownChosen = rbPaymentToVendor.Checked;
        . . .
}
```

I then try to set them back at the end of that same handler (the Save button's click event) like so:

```
if (paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen)
{
    //rbPaymentToIndividual.Checked = true; <= This didn't work - jQuery does not respond to programatic clicks!
    ddlPaymentToIndividual.Visible = true;
}
```

The code is reached, and the Visible value set to true (provided I had made the dropdown visible by checking "rbPaymentToIndividual" prior to selecting the Save button, but it has no effect - the dropdown remains hidden.

As you can deduce from the commented-out code, I also tried programatically checking the radiobutton which, which when done manually, sets off the following client-side code:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

...but apparently jQuery does not respond to programatically-induced events.

Or is it a timing issue? Is it because the form is still in the "submit" phase/state that this is not working -- either the client-side or the server-side code, or both?

If that is the problem - the submit doesn't finish until after the Save button handler exits, and thus I'm setting the DropDown to visible too soon - where can I put the code to accomplish this setting of form state back to what it was before the submit? Is the Page_Load() event the place to do it and, if so, is there some property I can interrogate to determine if the form has just been submitted?

### UPDATE

I moved the code to the end of the Page_Load() event, like so:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) 
{
    if (paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen)
    {
        ddlPaymentToIndividual.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

...but, because the whole shebang starts fresh, paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen's initialized value of false is seen, and so my intentions, though good, are keeping company with brimstone.

So how *can* I revert to pre-submit state - is an .INI file, or Registry usage, or Cookie, the usual way to accomplish this?

### UPDATE 2

What seems to be very odd about this is that I *am* able to revert to the pre-submit state of an HTMLTable; this code is in the Save button click handler:

```
// Re-visiblize any rows with vals
if (RowContainsVals(3))
{
    foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(4))
{
    foapalrow4.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(5))
{
    foapalrow5.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(6))
{
    foapalrow6.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
```

...and it works fine (any rows with any vals are displayed, although at the beginning, only one row displays). Stranger yet, perhaps, is that the function:

```
private bool RowContainsVals(int rownum)
{
    bool rowdirty = false;
    switch (rownum)
    {
        case 3:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxIndex2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxOrganization2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAccount2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxActivity2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAmount2.Text)));
            break;
        case 4:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund3.Text)) ||
            . . .
```

...finds values in the input text boxes; if the state of the DropDownList being visible is lost during the submit, why are not the values in the TextBoxes/text input lost?

Something is rotten in Redmond (or somewhere).

### UPDATE 3

In response to , here is some more code relative to the two dropdowns in question:

Code-behind / C#:

```
rbPaymentToIndividual = new RadioButton
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    ID = "rbPaymentToIndividual"
};
rbPaymentToIndividual.Text = PAYMENT_OR_REIMBURSEMENT_TO_AN_INDIVIDUAL;
rbPaymentToIndividual.GroupName = "paymentTo";
rbPaymentToIndividual.Checked = false;
cellRadioButton1_1.Controls.Add(rbPaymentToIndividual);


rbPaymentToVendor = new RadioButton
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    ID = "rbPaymentToVendor"
};
rbPaymentToVendor.Text = PAYMENT_TO_A_VENDOR;
rbPaymentToVendor.GroupName = "paymentTo";
cellRadioButton2_1.Controls.Add(rbPaymentToVendor);
```

Rendered HTM from "View Source":

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_rbPaymentToIndividual" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$paymentTo" value="rbPaymentToIndividual" />

<input id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_rbPaymentToVendor" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$paymentTo" value="rbPaymentToVendor" />
```

Comment: You keep posting jQuery issues with no html. No way for us to know what those selectors refer to and be able to see what should or shouldn't be happening. If form is being submitted by browser default process page will reload. Not clear what process flow is here either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/trysel.asp)

[:checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

should work

Comment: I am using "if (this.checked) {" and it doesn't work when setting in C#: rbPaymentToIndividual.Checked = true;